# Image won't appear on my tkinter text widget

Tags: tkinter

I have been trying to get an image into my tkinter child window and when I run this code I receive no errors but I only get a series of numbers in the child window. Here is a piece of the code I have:

```
from tkinter import *
top = Tk('Outfit Randomizer')

#gender entry
L1 = Label(top, text = 'What is your gender? Type 1 for male and 2 for female')
L1.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
g = StringVar()
E1 = Entry(top, bd = 5, textvariable = g)
E1.grid(row = 0, column = 1)

#submit function
def submit():
    g.get()
    gender = g.get()
    if gender == '1':
        root = Toplevel()
        T = Text(root, height = 30, width = 90)
        T.pack()
        mhbs = random.choice([ms1, ms2]) 
        if mhbs == ms1:
            photo = PhotoImage(file = "m.GIF")
            label = Label(image = photo)
            label.image = photo
            label.pack()
        if mhbs == ms2:
            photo = PhotoImage(file = "m.GIF")
            label = Label(image = photo)
            label.image = photo
            label.pack()
        T.insert(END, T)

#submit button
MyButton1 = Button(top, text = 'Submit', width = 10, command = submit)
MyButton1.grid(row = 3, column = 1)

top.mainloop()
```

ms1 and ms2 are defined in a different part of my code where I create a male shirts class but I felt that was unnecessary for this question. Please let me know what I can do to get my image to transfer to the new window!

Comment: Please sea h this site about tk ter images not showing up. There must be at least 100 related questions

Comment: @BryanOakley I've searched this site as well as many others and there are related questions but I have yet to find an answer that works in my program

Comment: @sammy The image doesn't appear because the label is not packed. Look at the error messages. If you want somebody else to fix your code please post a [mcve] that they can actually run and see what happen.

Comment: The code you posted throws lots of errors.

Answer (score 0):

You have at least two problems.

First, you should never create more than one instance of `Tk` or call mainloop more than once. If you need another window, create an instance of `Toplevel`, and don't call `mainloop` a second time.

Two, Your image is getting garbage-collected because you are using a local variable to store the image. For more information see http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-do-my-tkinter-images-not-appear.htm

You are also putting the label in the root window rather than the instance of the `Toplevel` that you are creating, because you are neglecting to give the `Label` a parent.

Finally, I have no idea what you think `T.insert(END, T)` is supposed to do. It appears you're attempting to insert a widget into itself. a) this makes no sense, b) if you want to insert a widget into a text widget you must use the `window_create` method, and c) if your actual intention is to insert an image into a text widget then you don't need the `Label` and you can use `image_create` instead.

Comment: I've made all the changes you suggested and altered my code but I keep getting garbage-collected images! I updated my code in my post if you'd like to check and see if you can find where I'm going wrong.